# Gas in movement

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose I have a gas contained in a solid box and I drop it from a certain height, is the temperature of the gas going to change because of the velocity that it acquires during the fall? If so, by how much?

Comment: Temperature of a gas isn't related to the macro speed of the gas, but more to the fibrations and speed of individual atoms/molecules relative to its surrounding. So there will beno temperature increase of the gas due to the speed of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature of the gas will go up, **but only** after the box hits the ground and the falling gas swirls around and randomizes its velocity. The lost potential energy of the gas has to show up somewhere...

Comment: it would be interesting a simulation of this